# LIFO implementation - getting parcels

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a requirement in which I need to calculate whether a particular stock on hand has being held for more than X days (Let's assume X is 20). If it has been held less than X days, then it gets excluded from the calculation

For example

```
ID = 1       1st  Jan  Buy =  10      Total 10
ID = 2       2nd  Jan  Buy =  10      Total 20
ID = 3       15th Jan  Sell = 5       Total 15
ID = 4       2nd  Feb  Sell = 15      Total 0
```

So let's say on 14th Jan, we need to calculate how much stock we held on hand minus any stock that has been sold which hasn't been held for more than 20 days. In this case, we would get a result of 15 since on 15th Jan we sold 5 (the 5 units is tied to ID 2, so the time frame between 2nd Jan and 15th is less than 20 days, but the units sold on 2nd feb (tied to the 1st/2nd Jan batch) has been more than 20 days so is still included.

What I've implemenetd is an iterative solution - I've seen some CTE based solutions but I'm not sure if can be done for the above mentioned scenario. This is what my table looks like after implementing the iterative solution

```
ParentID              Child Id      Units
1                      1            10
---------------------------------------
2                      1            10
2                      2            10
---------------------------------------
3                      1            10
3                      2            10
3                      2            -5
---------------------------------------
4                      1             10
4                      2             5
4                      2             -5
4                      1             -10
```

This is what the end result of the table using the iterative solution. Using this table, I can easily check any at whatever point in time, the parcels that make up the total amount and whether any sells that were made in the future (using cross apply).

Comment: need to see the original schema

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.